# Status still " Editor Assignment Pending" after 8 weeks

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, journals, peer-review

I submitted my paper in Journal of Intelligent Information Systems (springer)
The journal says the average time from submission to decision is 1 month, but after 8 weeks the paper status is still listed as "Editor Assignment Pending".
I tried to contact the editor in chief and he said"The Editor is still in the process of evaluating your paper as well as finding suitable and able referees."
 is it normal?